# Which Coldfusion development setup for learning?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm about to move from a PHP job to a Coldfusion job. I've never used it before and I'd like to get up to speed quickly.

I use a Mac at home (10.5) so what would be the best free development platform to learn on and what are the latest and best tutorials?

Currently I use Netbeans as an IDE but I could be persuaded to use Eclipse if there is no other option.

Comment: I have a Mac as well and use CF9 Dev edition and Coda (but CFBuilder/CFEclipse might work better since you are new with better code hinting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

free IDE?

- http://www.cfeclipse.org/

paid IDE?

- http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/features/

more IDE: http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#editors

Where to learn CF? search stackoverflow, read Adobe's web dev guide / doc

Comment: Thanks. That carehart site is one BIG page! How should I go about setting up a server? I've looked briefly at BlueDragon and Smith or should I just go with the free CF dev edition?

Comment: Find out what ver u'll be working on first, if they don't care, download CF9.  Install it as dev edition, you're good to go.  You may use the built-in web server.

Comment: If you already have the latest Dreamweaver, it isn't bad either.  I prefer CFBuilder though.  CfEclipse is great as well.

Comment: They use Dreamweaver at my new job. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

HI Leo,
         Welcome to CF World,
For learning you can use this site http://easycfm.com/
If you have doubts, you can put in this forum. Or there are numerous CF forums there...
Even Adobe ColdFusion forum is there...

You can also look at some experts blogs like coldfusionjedi.com, bennadel.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out www.lynda.com for some solid CF training.  $25 for the month and you'll be on your way and you can get the rest figured out as you go